# Windows batch file - how to loop through files in a directory?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I have this batch:

```
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b *.pdf') do call convert.exe %%a
```

This gets every pdf file thats in the same folder as convert.exe. I want to be able to say where the PDF resides. What do I have to change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the directory name can be hardcoded, then it will be

```
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b /s "Disk:\Your\Directory\Name\*.pdf"') do call convert.exe %%a
```

Note that this will also return all .pdf files in subdirectories of Disk:\Your\Directory\Name.

Comment: I think /b is wrong, I need the full path ... right now, I only get the filename, not the full path. And thus the param for convert.exe is only a file, without path.

Comment: @EOB: If you need to get full paths then you need to add /s, but leave /b. Modified my answer accordingly. /b suppresses `dir` headers in output - you definitely don't want them for batch processing.

Comment: Notice: For in () do requires '(' and ')' in Windows 7 command line