# windows batch file rename

Tags: batch-file, rename

I have some file such as `AAA_a001.jpg`, `BBB_a002.jpg`, `CCC_a003.jpg` in Windows 7
and I'm trying to use batch to rename these file to `a001_AAA.jpg`, `a002_BBB.jpg`, `a003_CCC.jpg`.

Just to swap the content between `_`.

I have been searching for a while, but still don't know how to do this.
Can anyone help? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
@echo off
pushd "pathToYourFolder" || exit /b
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *_*.jpg') do (
  for /f "tokens=1* eol=_ delims=_" %%A in ("%%~nF") do ren "%%F" "%%~nB_%%A%%~xF"
)
popd
```

Note: The name is split at the first occurrence of `_`. If a file is named "part1_part2_part3.jpg", then it will be renamed to "part2_part3_part1.jpg"

Comment: still a minor problem: it swap ".jpg" too. Ex. part1_part2.jpg => part2.jpg_part1  Orz

Comment: @raphael0914 - ??? It works perfectly for me: part1_part2.jpg --> part2_part1.jpg

Answer (score 56):

Use `REN` Command

`Ren` is for `rename`

```
ren ( where the file is located ) ( the new name )
```

example

```
ren C:\Users\&username%\Desktop\aaa.txt bbb.txt
```

> it will change aaa.txt to bbb.txt

Your code will be :

```
ren (file located)AAA_a001.jpg a001.AAA.jpg

ren (file located)BBB_a002.jpg a002.BBB.jpg

ren (file located)CCC_a003.jpg a003.CCC.jpg
```

and so on

```
IT WILL NOT WORK IF THERE IS SPACES!
```

Hope it helps :D

Comment: `just to swap the content between '_'` Do you understand what the question is?

Comment: I know I should use ren to rename the file, but my problem is I don't know how to do those string manipulations Orz

Comment: Not really :/ Please use a **good explanation of swap the content**?

Comment: There's a pattern that goes like `PART1_PART2.EXT` and OP wants to rename all files in a certain directory to `PART2_PART1.EXT`. I guess :P

Comment: I want to swap the content between '_', Ex: AAA_BBB.txt => BBB_AAA.txt

Comment: sorry for the confusing =P

Comment: I still dont understand... well at least i helped .. :(

Comment: So thats mean you swapping the contect of File a to file b? is that the explanation?

Comment: @Itsproinc OP is trying to do exactly what you are doing but without having to write it for every filename in the folder he's on.

Comment: =="? and what is op i know op is operator ( in minecraft )

Comment: @Itsproinc Come on, stay! OP means original poster. Wait here a bit and you'll see a good answer coming, and you'll benefit as well.

Comment: If you try to run this in batch script you get the error ```The syntax of the command is incorrect.```

Answer (score 12):

as Itsproinc said, the `REN` command works!

but if your file path/name has spaces, use quotes " "

example:

```
ren C:\Users\&username%\Desktop\my file.txt not my file.txt
```

add " "

```
ren "C:\Users\&username%\Desktop\my file.txt" "not my file.txt"
```

hope it helps

Comment: Note to others ... this only works with backslashes and will throw an error with forward slashes "cannot find file"

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you know the length of the part before the `_` and after the underscore, as well as the extension. If you don't it might be more complex than a simple substring.

```
cd C:\path\to\the\files
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b *.jpg') do (
set p=%a:~0,3%
set q=%a:~4,4%
set b=%p_%q.jpg
ren %a %b
)
```

I just came up with this script, and I did not test it. Check out [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#String_processing) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836368/windows-batch-file-how-to-loop-through-files-in-a-directory) for more info.

IF you want to assume you don't know the positions of the `_` and the lengths and the extension, I think you could do something with for loops to check the index of the `_`, then the last index of the `.`, wrap it in a `goto` thing and make it work. If you're willing to go through that trouble, I'd suggest you use WindowsPowerShell (or Cygwin) at least (for your own sake) or install a more advanced scripting language (think Python/Perl) you'll get more support either way.

Answer (score 0):

I rename in code

```
echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    REM echo %%a
    set x=%%a
    set mes=!x:~17,3!

    if !mes!==JAN (
        set mes=01
    )

    if !mes!==ENE (
        set mes=01
    )

    if !mes!==FEB (
        set mes=02
    )

    if !mes!==MAR (
        set mes=03
    )

    if !mes!==APR (
        set mes=04
    )

    if !mes!==MAY (
        set mes=05
    )

    if !mes!==JUN (
        set mes=06
    )

    if !mes!==JUL (
        set mes=07
    )

    if !mes!==AUG (
        set mes=08
    )

    if !mes!==SEP (
        set mes=09
    )

    if !mes!==OCT (
        set mes=10
    )

    if !mes!==NOV (
        set mes=11
    )

    if !mes!==DEC (
        set mes=12
    )

    ren %%a !x:~20,4!!mes!!x:~15,2!.txt 

    echo !x:~20,4!!mes!!x:~15,2!.txt 

)
```

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell way works for me and easier to understand and change. However, got errors like `rename-item : Source and destination path must be different` until I changed it a bit.
To rename files of the folder only:

> dir | Where-Object {$*.Name -match 'replaceMe'} | Rename-Item -NewName { $*.Name -replace 'replaceMe','myNewText' }

To rename files of the folder and sub folders recursively:

> Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$*.Name -match '.Core.'} | Rename-Item -NewName { $*.Name -replace '.Core.','.Framework.' }

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one code:

```
echo off
cd D:\TEMP
for %%A IN (*.jpg) do (
 call :dothings "%%A"
)
cd D:\2
goto :eof

:dothings
set A=%1
set P=%A:~1,12%
set Q=%A:~14,4%
set B="%Q% %P%.jpg"
ren %a% %b%
goto :eof
```

it will rename for example "Untitled-227 1965.jpg" to "1965 Untitled-227.jpg"

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution via PowerShell :

`dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace "replaceME","MyNewTxt"}`

This will rename parts of all the files in the current folder.

Comment: there is something strange going on here, since this mangled the file names. Perhaps the -replace param takes in regex or something