# Windows batch file renaming via reordering current name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a large amount of files in a folder, the file name format is: "ID FIRSTNAME LASTNAME.extension". The ID is either 7 digits or 6 digits and an X i.e., 1234567 or 123456X. The extension is either pdf, doc or docx. The delimiter between each variable is a space " ". Example "1234567 Jill Smith.pdf"

I need to rename each file by reordering the current name. Instead of "ID FIRSTNAME LASTNAME.extension", it needs to be "LASTNAME_FIRSTNAME_ID.extension". 
Thus I need to swap LASTNAME with ID and replace all white space with underscores "_". The extension needs to be unchanged. Using the above example, "Smith_Jill_1234567.pdf".

I have done some quick cleaning (no middle names) but I am uncertain how to get the rename command to work on the second delimiter, not the first. I have looked at [windows batch file rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013145/windows-batch-file-rename), however this only acts on the first delimiter.

I do not have access to third party software (restricted permissions), I am running Windows 7 and I have checked that Powershell is usable.

I would appreciate any help on this, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=. " %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
  SET "reqxt="
  IF /i "%%d"=="pdf" SET reqxt=Y
  IF /i "%%d"=="doc" SET reqxt=Y
  IF /i "%%d"=="docx" SET reqxt=Y
  IF DEFINED reqxt (
   ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\%%a %%b %%c.%%d" "%%c_%%b_%%a.%%d"
  )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

should report the required `RENAME`s after you change the source directory name. Remove the `ECHO` keyword to actually perform the rename.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '^(\w+) (\w+) (\w+)', '$3_$2_$1'}
```