# rename file name by using batch file

Tags: batch-rename

I want to replace '`_`' by '`-`' in file names. however, dos can't recognize the variable value(`%str%`) in do loops, it works well outside of the loop(`%str1%` can be displayed), does anyone have an idea about it? thank you in advance!
codes:

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\Users\Documents\tasks\STATS\27feb\try" || exit /b
set str1=jump1_over_the_chair
set str1=%str1:_=-%
echo str1=%str1%
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.doc') do (
    set "File=%%a"
    set str=jump_over_the_chair
    set str=%str:_=-%
    echo %str%
    pause
    ren "%%a" "%str%"
)
popd
```

Comment: did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/14013145/6689101

Comment: improved formatting